# I am not able to see a New option or create databases in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[No New Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwyXm.png)

I earlier had the New option, but it disappeared after I deleted one of my past databases. I am not also able to create another new database as I have "no privileges." I added myself as a user, but I am not sure how I would be able to create a database.

Comment: Did you give yourself ADMIN rights for that user? Check out the user preferences and make sure you have given the appropriate rights to the user you are logged in as.

Comment: Click on the `home icon` => `user accounts` => `edit privileges` then check `structure` options and make sure `create` is selected. On my local machine I user `super user` privileges and select all options.